# Finding equations for the horizontal tangents to a curve?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

Can anyone verify if I am doing the following correct? One of the practice problems in my book says to **Find equations for the horizontal tangents to the curve $y=x^3-3x-2$.**

I have the following worked out via derivatives:

$y=x^3-3x-2$
$y^1=3x^2-3$
$0=3x^2-3$
$3=3x^2$
$3/3 = x^2$
$1=x^2$
$sqrt(1)=sqrt(x^2)$
$1=x$

I then plugged **1** inf or **x** in my original equation:

$y=(1)^3-3(1)-2$
$y=1-3-2$
$y=-4$

There is a horizontal tangent at Point(1,-4). Then based on my [graph](http://www.meta-calculator.com/online/?panel-102-graph&data-bounds-xMin=-10&data-bounds-xMax=10&data-bounds-yMin=-7.28&data-bounds-yMax=7.28&data-equations-0=%22y%3Dx%5E3-3*x-2%22&data-rand=undefined&data-hideGrid=false) for $y=x^3-3x-2$, I believe there is also a horizontal tangent at Point(-1,0) along the origin? Thus I plugged in **0** for **x** in my original equation as well:

$y=(0)^3-3(0)-2$
$y=0-0-2$
$y=-2$

This then would be Point (0,-2), but that is not a horizontal tangent on my graph?

Comment: The derivative isn't equal to $0$ at $x=0$, so why do you think that?

Comment: Maybe too much arithmetical detail. Also, $x^2=1$ has two solutions, $x=\pm 1$.

Comment: @JessicaK, I'm trying to figure this out and refresh myself after a week away due to a work conference. Am I incorrect that my horizontal tangents for this particular graph would be (-1,0) and (1,-4)?

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic These points are right and thus $x=0$ is not to be considered

Comment: @imranfat, Thanks. I guess I'm just confused on how I would find the (-1,0) point without just knowing/looking at the shape of my graph in this case?

Comment: Interesting username you have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first tangent is correct. For the second tangent, note that $x^2=1$ has another root at $x=-1$.

Alternatively, note that
$$y=x^3-3x-2=(x+1)^2(x-2)$$
This means there is a double root at $x=-1$, so the x-axis itself ($y=0$) is a horizontal tangent.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up a bit! And thanks for the compliment. I came up with the name back in my first IT Job as a Data Analyst.

Comment: You're welcome!